# corrupted email attachments in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I'm trying to attach a PDF attachment to an email being sent with System.Net.Mail.  The attachment-adding part looks like this:

```
using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    pdfStream.Write(pdfData, 0, pdfData.Length);

    Attachment a = new Attachment(pdfStream, 
        string.Format("Receipt_{0}_{1}.pdf", jobId, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")));

    msg.Attachments.Add(a);

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(serverName, port);
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmailName, fromEmailPassword);
    smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

The problem is that the attachment gets corrupted on the other end.  I found some discussion of this problem [here](http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.4.8.aspx), however  the solution mentioned on that page used System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment, which was made obsolete in .NET 2.0.

I've tried changing the TransferEncoding in the Attachment class (which replaces MailAttachment), but had no luck.  Has anyone solved this on .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `pdfStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin)` before creating the attachment to reset the stream to the beginning?

Comment: Yup, that was it.  I guess the whole encoding thing was a red herring :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to make sure that the PDF document isn't already corrupted in the pdfData array? Try writing that to a file then opening it.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    byte[] contentAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(EnterFileLocationOnDisk);

    memoryStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);

    // Set the position to the beginning of the stream.
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Create attachment
    ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
    //Pick correct media type Octet/PDF/Zip etc.
    contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
    contentType.Name = EnterFileName;
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, contentType);

    // Add the attachment
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    // Send Mail via SmtpClient
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Of course declare MailMessage() and SmtpClient(). My snippet only shows how to add attachment to MailMessage via memory stream. Your problem was not resetting MemoryStream which is memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);